# Multiple Flyways with FlywayMigrationStrategy

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have multiple `Flyway` datasources  and need to implement `FlywayMigrationStrategy` to them. Each datasource has their own `flyway_migration` table etc.

But when I create `FlywayMigrationStrategy` it will not be called.

This doesn't work:

```
@Bean
public FlywayMigrationStrategy cleanMigrateStrategy() { ...
```

This works:

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void cleanBeforeMigrate(
      @Qualifier("dpaFlyway") Flyway dpaflyway,
      @Qualifier("flyway") Flyway flyway) {

    dpaflyway.clean();
    dpaflyway.migrate();

    flyway.clean();
    flyway.migrate();
  }
```

Are there better options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you implement `@PostContruct` method? As I see, `FlywayMigrationStrategy` is a functional interface and I guess that your code should look like this:

```
@Bean
public FlywayMigrationStrategy cleanMigrateStrategy() {
    FlywayMigrationStrategy strategy = new FlywayMigrationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
            flyway.clean();
            flyway.migrate();
        }
    };

    return strategy;
}
```

---

Ok, I have some research and now can explain the answer to your question.

First of all, let's check the `FlywayAutoConfiguration`

When you use configuring flyway migration via a property file, the configuration works, creates and configures Flyway instances and migrates base. All of these are configured in `FlywayConfiguration`. Let's look on the condition annotation on the configuration

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Flyway.class)
```

This means that configuration isn't created if bean for class `Flyway.class` already exists in the spring context. Ok, next, the configuration creates only to beans

```
@Bean
public Flyway flyway(FlywayProperties properties, DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties,
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader, ObjectProvider<DataSource> dataSource,
        @FlywayDataSource ObjectProvider<DataSource> flywayDataSource,
        ObjectProvider<FlywayConfigurationCustomizer> fluentConfigurationCustomizers,
        ObjectProvider<JavaMigration> javaMigrations, ObjectProvider<Callback> callbacks)
.....
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(Flyway flyway,
        ObjectProvider<FlywayMigrationStrategy> migrationStrategy) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, migrationStrategy.getIfAvailable());
}
```

It's not so important how the config configures the `flyway` bean, but it important that it creates `FlywayMigrationInitializer`, which initiate migration. As you can see, `FlywayMigrationStrategy` is set to `FlywayMigrationInitializer` as constructor argument. And it is he who uses the MigrationStrategy if it was set, otherwise just execute `flyway.migrate()`. (see source code)

Ok, now we know how it works in general, let's see in your code.

You create to flyway instances in your main configuration:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
@FlywayDataSource
public Flyway firstFlyway(DataSource dataSource) {
  return new Flyway(
      new FluentConfiguration()
          .locations("db/first-migration")
          .schemas("first")
          .outOfOrder(true)
          .dataSource(dataSource)
  );
}

@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
@FlywayDataSource
public Flyway secondFlyway(@Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
  return new Flyway(
      new FluentConfiguration()
          .dataSource(dataSource)
          .schemas("second")
          .outOfOrder(true)
          .locations("db/second-migration")
  );
}
```

Since you already create Flyway instances, `FlywayConfiguration` isn't created( due to the condition) and Initializer beans for your `Flyway` beans also aren't created. As a result migrations aren't executed and you need to add `(initMethod = "migrate")` to bean declaration for starting the migration.
Also, I think the `@FlywayDataSource` is not required and do nothing.

Let's now go to your test configuration.

When you creating `FlywayMigrationStrategy`, it works correctly, but no one use the strategy (in your main config file you call `Flyway.migrate` just as initMethod and MigrationInitializer isn't created). As a result, the strategy isn't executed.

In your working example, you added calling clean and migrate in `TestConfiguration` postconstruct method. And it works because postconstruct method is executed after configuration was created. **BUT** if you debug your code, you will see that `migrate` method is executed twice for each Flyway instances: as a bean `initMethod` and from Testconfiguration postcontruct method. I'm not sure that it is what you want.

Ok, for fixing it, I suggest remove `(initMethod = "migrate")` and `@FlywayDataSource`, create `FlywayMigrationInitializer` bean for each `Flyway` bean in your main configuration and implement `FlywayMigrationStrategy` in your test config.

```
@Bean
public FlywayMigrationInitializer flywayInitializer(@Qualifier(...) Flyway flyway,
        ObjectProvider<FlywayMigrationStrategy> migrationStrategy) {
        return new FlywayMigrationInitializer(flyway, migrationStrategy.getIfAvailable());
}
```

Comment: This will not run at all when you have multiple flyway beans. The bean will be created but the `migrate(Flyway)` method will not be called.

Comment: I'll update my anwser to include that the default way, that you suggest, does not work.

Comment: Could you please show the full code of class with your `cleanBeforeMigrate`? As I know, init method should be no-arg method. I've tried to create a bean with init method with arguments, but I have an exception `Lifecycle method annotation requires a no-arg method`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mihkell/ac0ea5c47655ec29066f34fafb180bf7

Comment: I expanded my answer